# Jacobian of second norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Find the Jacobian of the following function:

(a) $f(x)= \|x -x_0 \|_2$

(b) $f(x)= \log(\|x \|_2)$

Please give me some serious hint!!

Comment: So is $x$ in $\Bbb R^2$?

Answer (score 3):

The function $\phi(x) = \|x\|_2^2= x^T x$ is straightforward to differentiate
since $\phi(x+h)-\phi(x) = 2 x^T h + h^T h$, hence $D \phi(x) = 2 x^T$.

The function $T(x) = x-x_0$ is affine, hence $DT(x) = I$.

The function $s(t) = \sqrt{t}$ has derivative $Ds(t) = {1 \over 2 \sqrt{t}}$.

(a) Since $f = s \circ \phi \circ T$, we know $D \log(t) = {1 \over t}$ so the chain rule gives
$Df(x) = Ds(\phi(T(x))) D \phi(T(x)) D T(x)$, and so

> $Df(x) = {1 \over 2\|x-x_0\|_2}(2 (x-x_0)^T) I = {x -x_0 \over \|x-x_0\|_2}$

(b) We can write $f(x) = \log \|x\|_2 = {1 \over 2} \log \|x\|_2^2$ and
so $f = {1 \over 2} \log \circ \phi$. The chain rule gives
$Df(x) = {1 \over 2} D \log(\phi(x)) D \phi(x)$, and so

> $Df(x) =  {1 \over2} {1 \over \|x\|_2^2} 2 x^T= {x^T \over \|x\|_2^2 }$